# Adding a member variable to my iterator class causes Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, class, templates, iterator, operators

I have a templated iterator class:

```
template <class number_type, class label_type>
class DepthIterator {
public:
    // CONSTRUCTOR / COPY / ASSIGN / DECONSTRUCTOR
    DepthIterator() : ptr_(NULL) {}
    DepthIterator(Node<number_type, label_type>* n) : ptr_(n) {}
    DepthIterator(const DepthIterator& old) : ptr_(old.ptr_), visited(old.visited) {}
    ~DepthIterator() {}

    // OPERATORS
    DepthIterator& operator=(const DepthIterator& old) { ptr_ = old.ptr_; return *this; }
    const Point<number_type>& operator*() const { return ptr_->pt; }
    bool operator== (const DepthIterator& rgt) { return ptr_ == rgt.ptr_; }
    bool operator!= (const DepthIterator& rgt) { return ptr_ != rgt.ptr_; }


    // ++ DEPTH FIRST ITERATOR
    DepthIterator& operator++() {
        if (ptr_->children[0] == NULL && ptr_->children[1] == NULL) {
            // we're at a leaf, so go up one and back down and add to visited list
            visited.push_back(ptr_);
            ptr_ = ptr_->parent;
            return *this;
        } 
        else {
            // do stuff
        }


private:
    Node<number_type, label_type>* ptr_;
    std::vector<Node<number_type,label_type>* > visited; // causes problem
};
```

When the second to last line `std::vector<Node<number_type, label_type,>* > visited;` is removed, my program compiles and runs fine (provided that the ++ operator is commented out). However, adding this line to private in this class causes my program to compile but crash halfway through running. Aborted (core dumped).

I did some testing and any std::vector variable I add to this class seems to cause it to crash regardless of what it is.

Why is a variable causing this? How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: But I strongly suspect you are accessing some invalid pointer; or an out-of-range pointer which perhaps attempts to corrupt the next class member

Comment: I bet what makes a difference is not "`visited` is removed" but "the ++ operator is commented out". Which would be easy to verify - comment out the operator as before, but keep the variable declaration in. Basically, there's a problem in the code you haven't shown; when that code doesn't run, the problem disappears.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Children is a member of my node class

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When I comment out the ++ operator, the code still will not run. It seems adding any vector type member variable causes the crash.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't `operator*()` the problem? I mean: what about `return ptr_->pt;` if `ptr_` is null? Same problem in `operator++()`.

Comment: I think it has to do with the vector initialization, that it's not initializing properly and so my code is trying to delete it before it exists. How do I initialize my vector?